# MVC 5 want to export to PDF it's exporting but login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5

this the action which should be expoert: 
1- visual studio 2015 mvc 5 and installed package **Rotativa** for PDF

```
        [Authorize(Roles = "admin,operator")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Students.ToList());
        }
```

up action has responsibility to select some value and show in the view, view is partial

this can be view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectOne.Models.Student>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StatusName)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>

    </tr>
}
</table>
@Html.ActionLink("Export", "ExportIndex")    //this will run ExportIndex
```

this is the ExportIndex:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "admin,operator")]
    public ActionResult ExportIndex(int ? id)
    {
        return new ActionAsPdf("Index") { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
    }
```

Now after the Exporting Problem is it will create pdf but the login screen pdf don't what is wrong even I am login with same role user, here if I change the authorize to [AllowAnonymous] it will work but I need the permission this is the page which it will export to pdf in case of roles applied.

[image is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC263.png)

Comment: I believe you are using "Rotativa" (and not Relative) nuget package to generate PDF. Can you try "ViewAsPdf" instead of "ActionAsPdf"?

Comment: @Nirman The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType3`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Answer (score 0):

You need to include cookies in `ActionAsPdf` object intializer

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin,operator")]
public ActionResult ExportIndex(int?id)
{
    var cookies = Request.Cookies.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => Request.Cookies[k].Value); 
    return new ActionAsPdf("Index")
    {
        FileName = "Test.pdf", 
        FormsAuthenticationCookieName = System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
        Cookies = cookies 
    }; 

}
```